# Does a written language exist with 1 symbol for every word?

Tags: written-language

We could create a dense written language with 1 symbol for every word.

Lets say that it is read by a computer aloud or translated into normal language.(Like a QR code)

I know that QR code does something similar, but they represent data with ones and zeros instead of whole words and is very limited in the information capacity. We can't put a whole book in a QR code.

I know that currently the most dense written language is mandarin, but it is meant to be read by a human, so less physically compact.

Did somebody already did that ? If no, why would you think it is not done ?

Comment: The answer to the "why not" should be clear from looking at barcode versions of https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=moose&style=197&type=C128B&width=115&height=50&xres=1&font=3 versus https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=noose&style=197&type=C128B&width=115&height=50&xres=1&font=3

Comment: @user6726 I don't understand your point. Bar codes are physical representation of ones and zeros. If you represent data binary its always going to be very long. (ie the word cat is 011000110110000101110100). Would it not be more efficient to have a more compact written language for some situations ?

Comment: Everything can be called a representation of 1s and 0s. The question is how complex the difference can be between two symbols, given human cognition. Simply put, it is not *possible* to memorize and reliably perceive 10,000 distinct symbols. And btw 10,000 symbols is a seriously impoverished vocabulary.

Comment: @user6726 you're 100% right on human cognition, but in my question I said "Lets say that it is read by a computer aloud or translated into normal language". The goal of such a written language would be to be as dense as possible and to be read by a computer by OCR.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, having a single symbol for every word wouldn't be particularly useful. For starters, there would be no way to create new words.

If you allow putting words together to make new words (basically making it one symbol per *morpheme*, or shifting your definition of what a word is), then that's basically what the Han logography (most notably used for Mandarin) is.

If you want to make it computer-readable, Unicode (and various other encoding systems which encompass Han characters) does that: the character `四` ("four") is represented in Unicode by the number 0x56DB, for example. This can be represented as a QR code, bar code, or any other computer-readable means of representing numbers.

Comment: I think Chinese characters cannot be treated as single symbols: a character can have at least 3 symbols

Comment: For new words you could just create a new symbol. I understand with binary we can represent Mandarin symbol (or character), but would it not be more compact to just have 1 symbol per word ?